# Table pagination using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm having problems using jQuery to paginate a table on my webProject here is my code, I cant see what am I doing wrong

here is my html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${ctx}/js/device/device.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${ctx}/js/jquery/jquery.paginate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${ctx}/js/jquery/jquey.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${ctx}/css/paginate.css" media="screen" />

<table id="deviceholder">
        <c:forEach var="device" items="${devices}">
            <tr>
                <td><a href="<c:url value="/device/update/${device.id}"/>">${device.name}</a></td>
                <td><a href="<c:url value="/device/update/${device.id}"/>">${device.code}</a></td>
                <td><a href="<c:url value="/comandos/${device.id}"/>"><img
                        src="${ctx}/images/comandos.png" alt="Comandos" title="Comandos"></a></td>
                <td><a id="${device.id}" class="delete" href="#"><img
                        src="${ctx}/images/editar.png" alt="Editar" title="Editar"></a></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
        </table>
```

here is my javaScript

```
$("deviceholder").paginate({
        start       : 1,
        display     : 8,
        border                  : true,
        border_color            : '#fff',
        text_color              : '#fff',
        background_color        : 'black',  
        border_hover_color      : '#ccc',
        text_hover_color        : '#000',
        background_hover_color  : '#fff', 
        images                  : false,
        mouse                   : 'press'});
```

Comment: What exactly is going wrong? Can you post a jsfiddle? http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: my table loads but it doesn pagintate acording, all the data is loaded but as if the method was never called

Comment: There is a typo `src="${ctx}/js/jquery/jquey.js"`

Comment: i'm correting it let me try it for a sec

Comment: I would recommend to use datatables plugin [datatables.net](http://www.datatables.net/) You can easily set up your pagination, modify sorting, get serverside data and much more.
Just have a look at the examples following the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this change

```
$("#deviceholder").paginate({
```

Note the `#` at the start of the selector to find the element with that id.

[Selector Reference](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

---

There are a number of paginate plugins... which one are you using?

Also, not matter which one you want to load it after jQuery.  That is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${ctx}/js/jquery/jquey.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${ctx}/js/jquery/jquery.paginate.js"></script>
```

not

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${ctx}/js/jquery/jquery.paginate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${ctx}/js/jquery/jquey.js"></script>
```

Comment: yep I tried it was wrong also but ir still not working for me I'm going to check the imports on the css it may be missing